# Lightbox com rails admin

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, lightbox

Galera, estou querendo implementar uma forma de "ampliar" a imagem do produto quando ele for clickado. Já vi alguns tutoriais, gem's e nada funciona. Pelo que pesquisei seria oq o jquery Lightbox faz. Alguém já teve que fazer isso e sabe uma maneira de me ajudar? .-.﻿
Grato pela ajuda!

Comment: O rails admin tem alguma particularidade ou ele é um HTML comum que aceita jQuery e CSS? Digo, um exemplo simples em HTML/CSS serviria pra vc?

Comment: Ele tem particularidades. Eu não mexo diretamente no HTML e CSS/JS dele. Existem Gem's (bibliotecas) que são preparadas pra utilização via rails (para realizar alterações), mas como sou iniciantes nisso, esse é um dos problemas.